# Sage Line 50 ADODB connection with Classic ASP on IIS6 - Authentication Failed

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-6, adodb, sage-line-50

We have a classic asp page running on IIS6, which connects to our Sage Line 50 (v17) with the following code:

```vb
'Create an ADO connection object
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next

adoCon.ConnectionTimeout = 0
ConStr="dsn=SageLine50v17;UID=uid;Password=pwd;"
adoCon.Open ConStr

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    Response.Write (Err.Description& "<br><br>")
    Response.Write (Err.Number)
    Response.End

End If
```

This works perfectly most of the time.  However, occasionally, it throws the following error:

Authentication failed
-2147217843

My question is, what is causing the error?  I'm thinking it is Sage throwing it back, but on searching for the error number (-2147217843!), I find nothing online.

Comment: For google convert to hex: 80040E4D

Comment: [Err Msg: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers Error '80040e4d'](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222828)

Comment: Thank you for the hex conversion tip Alex K, and for the link Lankymart, hopefully they will help us to find the cause.

Comment: This is most likely a problem on the database provider side, not yours. Most you can do in case of a failure is try again, assuming those are one-time glitches.

Answer (score 0):

I would test the DSN in excel or access then I would check the iis usr has permissions on the sage accdata folder :)